# The product of Weyl groups is the Weyl group of the product

Tags: lie-groups, coxeter-groups

Let $G$ and $H$ be compact, connected Lie groups. Write $W(-)$ for the Weyl group. Then it is not hard to see that
$$W(G \times H) \cong W(G) \times W(H).$$
Where can I find a published statement of this fact?

Comment: We are currently snowed out of campus, so I can't check my books, but I suspect it's in Fulton and Harris somewhere.  But anyway, certainly the result is easy enough that either you can brush it away "it is well known that...", or you can include a very brief proof.....

Comment: I'm sorry to hear things are that bad that far south; I somehow just assumed it was mostly the northeast and midwest that were suffering. I just checked a PDF of Fulton & Harris, and it's not there. I'd checked about five other books, but it wasn't there either. All people tend to do with the Weyl group is describe its transitivity on Weyl chambers. I was mildly scolded by a referee for including a brief proof (less than an inch vertically) of this fact, so I guess that's not the done thing. It's already true that $(G,K) \mapsto N_G(K)$ is a product-preserving functor; is it representable?